# Android: How to Resolve Transitive Dependency Conflicts with Deprecations

Tags: android, gradle

I have an Android application which I've modularized so that it can be included in other projects as a dependency.

This module depends on libraries like Dagger and Retrofit.

What I'm seeing is that transitive dependencies from this module are conflicting with previous versions existing within the parent consumer application.

For example, if the parent is using Dagger 2.9 and the module is using 2.24, then Gradle resolves this dependency to 2.24 which causes breaking changes in the parent app due to deprecations or other various reasons.

I've tried excluding these conflicting dependencies within my Gradle configuration but then this causes the module to break.

How can I resolve this issue? Do I need to force the parent application to update dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

The parent would need to force the use of the correct dependency by doing:

```
implementation('com.google.dagger:dagger:2.x') {
    force = true
}
```

or if you are using `api`:

```
api ('com.google.dagger:dagger:2.x'){
     force = true
}
```

For more information you can reference the [Gradle Docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/managing_transitive_dependencies.html).

Comment: So this would force the module dependency version to match the parent dependency? Would this cause the module code to crash when it attempts to invoke some functionality that doesn't exist on a previous version?

Comment: This would would force the app to use the defined dependency. From what you described the module dependency is forcing the app to use the lower level. If that is the case, then you wouldn't have to worry about the module using the higher version because unless there was a major change, the module wouldn't be using the newer features.

Comment: Gradle is forcing the app to resolve from 2.9 -> 2.24 due to the newer version existing in the module. I'm just writing the module to use the latest version of Dagger (which has breaking changes from the earlier 2.9 version). I don't know what versions of Dagger, or other dependencies, consumers of this module are going to be using. Forcing version 2.9 in the app breaks the module. So it seems I'm stuck either way. Is the only solution to update the app dependencies to later versions?

Comment: I would force the app to use the version that is working, 2.9, and then force the module to use it's version, 2.24.

Comment: Interesting, it's possible to force in both? I would've thought it would lead to issues with both libraries being loaded into memory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198499/discussion-between-blackhatsamurai-and-masterwok).